# UserDefaults not working with MSMessagesAppViewController

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, messaging, userdefaults

I am trying to save data to UserDefaults using an UIAlertController , but the code fails to retrieve the data.

**Retrieve the Data**

```
    func displayCreatedPhrases(){
    phrases = uDefaults.stringArray(forKey: "createdPhrases") ?? [String]()
    print(phrases)
   }
```

**Setting the Data**

```
 self.uDefaults.set(textfield.text, forKey: "createdPhrases")
 self.uDefaults.synchronize()
 print("Saved the data!")
 self.phraseTableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `string` as a value for key 'createdPhrases' and then asking uDefaults to return an array of string?

```
func displayCreatedPhrases() {
    phrases = uDefaults.value(forKey: "createdPhrases") as? String
    print(phrases)
}
```

The above code should work for you.
Also no need to use below line ([Link to UserDefaults synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize))

```
self.uDefaults.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

`textfield.text` is of type `String?` and not `[String]`. In your code, you're saving the data as a `String` value and retrieving it as an `[String]` value. That's the reason, retrieving the data doesn't work.

**Solution:**

```
func displayCreatedPhrases(){
    phrases = uDefaults.string(forKey: "createdPhrases") ?? ""
    print(phrases)
}
```

Also, `phrases` must be of type `String`.